# javscript socket.io client is not receiving event

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, chat

So I'm trying to set up a socket.io chat with expressjs backend and sveltejs frontend.
I have a custom namespace called 'chat' and I create a new room on 'join' request.
I tried to stick very closely to official documentation.

Here is my code:
Server:

```
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3002);
log.info("Express server has started on port 3002");
const io = require("socket.io")(server, { path: "/api/express/socket.io" });
const chat = io.of("/chat");
chat.on("connection", socket => {
  log.info("New User connected");
  socket.on("join", room => {
    log.info("New User joined room: " + room);
    socket.join(room);
  });
  socket.on("chat message", data => {
    log.info("'chat-message'-Event: ", data);
    chat.in(data.room).emit("chat message", {
      room: data.room,
      msg: data.msg,
      user: data.user
    });
  });
});
```

Client:

```
let chatSocket
onMount(async () => {
    chatSocket = io('https://my.domain.com/chat', {
      path: '/api/express/socket.io',
      transports: ['websocket'],
    })
    chatSocket.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('chat message', function(data) {
         alert(data.msg)
      })
    })
    chatSocket.emit('join', 'Chat-Room#' + id)
  })
  const Submit = async e => {
    chatSocket.emit('chat message', {
      room: 'Chat-Room#' + id,
      msg: statusText,
      user,
    })
  }
```

According to the server console output everything seems to be setup fine. 
All the events are fired properly and logged to console.
But the clients don't seem to receive any 'chat message' events (they send them out just fine).
Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
chatSocket.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('chat message', function(data) {
         alert(data.msg)
      })
    })
```

You're registering the 'connection' event, an event that doesn't event exist in the latest socketIO version at least. This function never fires. Also, even if it did exist, you would still need to use the original "chatSocket" that you already established, and not "socket".

Change that piece of code to:

```
chatSocket.on('connect', function() {
      chatSocket.on('chat message', function(data) {
         alert(data.msg)
      })
    })
```

It's possible that maybe in older versions of socketIO the "connection" event existed, you need to take a look at the docs: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99

Notice that the event names in the frontend and server aren't the same. You have separate docs for each.

Comment: I adjusted the code the way you suggested. Still no event fired.
I also noticed that they suggested to register event handlers outside of the 'connect' event handler. I tried that as well but didn't have any luck either.

Comment: Can you upload the entire code to a repo/playground

Comment: I gave all the code that involves socket.io.
I can upload the rest but I don't see how that would be helpful.
Also this isn't running locally. It's on an actual server.

Comment: Actually now you got me thinking it might be due to my nginx reverse proxy.
I will check and give an update asap.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So apparently the problem was due to faulty nginx reverse proxy configuration.
I had added the 'upgrade' and 'connection' headers for the server but not for the client.
Fixing that resolved the issue.